# Web API controller action arguments are always null

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I did see a few threads here addressing similar issue but unfortunately nothing could solve my problem (so far).

**CONTROLLER METHOD**

Following is my controller method:

```cs
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
[RouteAttribute("SearchBooks")]
[HttpGet("searchbooks/{key}")]
public async Task<object> SearchBooks(string key)
{
    using (var cmd = _ctx.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SearchBooks";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Key", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = key });

        if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cmd.Connection.Open();

        var retObj = new List<dynamic>();
        using (var dataReader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
            {
                //Namespace for ExpandoObject: System.dynamic
                var dataRow = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

                for (var iFiled = 0; iFiled < dataReader.FieldCount; iFiled++)
                    dataRow.Add(dataReader.GetName(iFiled), dataReader[iFiled]);

                retObj.Add((ExpandoObject)dataRow);
            }
        }

        if (!retObj.Any())
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("No matching record found");
        else
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retObj);
    }
}
```

When I check the console for output it says

> fail: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel[13]
>   An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'SearchBooks' expects parameter '@Key', which was not supplied.

I have created another website locally, specially to test the CORS issue (which works fine). I am calling the above method via `AJAX` in the following way:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:5000/api/bookstore/SearchBooks",
  data: { 'key': 'van' },
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType:"application/json",
  success: function (res) {
    $("#response").html(res);
  },
  error: function (err) {

  }
});
</script>
```

Problem is the value of argument `key` in controller method `SearchBooks` is always `null`!

But if I create a `model` (below)

**MODEL**

```html
public class SearchViewModel{
  public string SearchKey {get; set;}
}
```

and then if I modify my `AJAX` to pass value to this `model` like following, everything works just fine!

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var searchModel={
    key: 'van'
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(searhModel),
    url: "http://localhost:5000/api/bookstore/searchbooks",
    contentType:"application/json",
    success: function (res) {
      $("#response").html(res);
    },
    error: function (err) {

    }
});
</script>
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you at least try to format your code correctly? Your first block is unreadable.

Comment: Tried to reformat the first code snippet but it still does not look very tidy :( Sorry for this

Comment: I've edited it a little bit, @NiladriSarkar

Comment: Thanks a lot Uwe Keim. It looks pretty now!

Comment: In your second attempt, you should have `var searchModel = { searchKey: 'van' }` in the javascript. Then, since you are sending json, use the action method signature `public async Task<object> SearchBooks([FromBody] SearchViewModel model) {` as in @Santosh's answer.

Comment: I will try this approach!

Answer (score 1):

Use `type: "GET"` in your ajax call

and your url should look like this 
`url: "http://localhost:5000/api/bookstore/SearchBooks/van"`
and finally remove `data`

final code:

```
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:5000/api/bookstore/SearchBooks/van",
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType:"application/json",
  success: function (res) {
    $("#response").html(res);
  },
  error: function (err) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter.

```
public async Task<object> SearchBooks([FromBody]string key){

}
```

Please refer [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: @CodeCaster:Updated the answer

Comment: Actually I tried `[FromBody]` already but that didn't work for me.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar:Are you able to hit the SearchBooks method in debug mode?

Comment: @NiladriSarkar:It's look like database issue not webapi issue

Comment: Its not a database issue because model binding from `JavaScript` and passing it as `JSON.stringify(model)` works fine. Problem is when I am passing arguments like `data: {'key': 'van'}`.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar:If you posting data then change the http verb to Post -[HttpPost("searchbooks/{key}")]

Answer (score 0):

according to your problem it seems that your json format is not valid, when you use stringify it generate valid json hence it works fine. So try to remove qouts from 'key' in your ajax call. e.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:5000/api/bookstore/SearchBooks",
  data: { key: 'van' },
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType:"application/json",
  success: function (res) {
    $("#response").html(res);
  },
  error: function (err) {

  }
});
</script>
```